# meaning of 百日のつもり

Tags: grammar, meaning, history

I am reading a book and found this paragraph that I don't understand
小生の命も後百日のつもりその間身のすりきれるほど働くつもり
I am getting that he intends to live what is left of his life working until his last breath.
I am not sure what 百日のつもり means. I have searched and found that 百日 means lots of days is that correct or there is an old meaning for this word?

Answer (score 3):

It consists of two sentences (where copula is omitted in both)

> 小生の命も後百日のつもり
>
> その間身のすりきれるほど働くつもり

In the first, 小生の命 is the subject to 後{あと}百日{ひゃくにち}. It literally means *(The rest of) my life is (only) another hundred days*. Since it is appended by のつもり, the speaker says s/he would pretend as if her/his life would end in 100 days.

Comment: sorry to ask again here is the full sentence 彼我戦力の差は益々歴然 たるものあり もはや最終 的段階と申すべき事態に突 入致し小生の命も後百日の つもりその間身のすりきれ るほど働くつもり」would you please share with me what he means by it? Does he mean he will work hard as if his life will end soon?

Comment: @JAM Freely translated, it means *Now that the difference in power between us and enemy is obvious, we are in the final stage. I'd assume I have only 100 days left for my life. I'll work to the end, till I'm worn down*. Is it a note of a WWII fighter or something?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have understood but was not very sure about the hundred days and why specifically 100 days, Yes it's part of Yamamoto Isoroku's diaries during WWII

Comment: @JAM Re 100 days, I guess it is just a random easy number, but he expected that  Japan couldn't fight more than a year (see [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E5%85%AD#%E7%AC%AC26%E4%BB%A3%E9%80%A3%E5%90%88%E8%89%A6%E9%9A%8A%E5%8F%B8%E4%BB%A4%E9%95%B7%E5%AE%98): 初め半年や1年の間は随分暴れてご覧に入れる。然しながら、2年3年となれば全く確信は持てぬ) so it could be that 100 days is just more or less literally what he thought (*I really have to finish the war in 100 days from now*).